# hypermedia.video.opencv.capture(III)V

Tags: opencv

I've downloaded OpenCV version 1 for my Windows 7 laptop from [this website](http://ubaa.net/shared/processing/opencv/). For some reason, whenever I try to run one of the example sketches like the `face_detection` or `threshold`, I get this error message:

> UnsatisfiedLinkError: hypermedia.video.opencv.capture(III)V

Have I downloaded the wrong version?

Comment: http://opencv.org/downloads.html - official OpenCV downloads.

Comment: why does this question get downvoted ?

Comment: @James Forbes Note that This particular OpenCV wrapper is old/outdated, but for basic tasks(filters(threshold,blur,etc.),blobs,haar cascade detection) will do. For an updated processing wrapper check out [this post](http://codeanticode.wordpress.com/2011/11/21/opencv-2-in-processing/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you've also installed [OpenCV 1.0](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-win/1.0/OpenCV_1.0.exe/download) itself, not just the Processing wrapper.

Also make sure the installer sets the **PATH** variable.

[image: OpenCV path]

At this point you should be able to run a basic sample which doesn't access the camera.
If not, you can check manually if the PATH variable includes the path to OpenCV in Environment Variables.

If you can run an OpenCV Processing sample without camera access but are getting errors when accessing the webcam try installing [WinDVIG_101](http://www.eden.net.nz/7/20071008/WinVDIG_101.exe).

On windows I sometimes found the OpenCV Processing wrapper sometimes worked with some Processing versions and not others. Try testing both Processing 2.0+ and Processing 1.5.1